# IIS rewrites cause 60 seconds response delay

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, url-rewriting, windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-edge

We have about 50 websites that share the same code (via symlink). Requests are handled by IIS 7.5 -> Tomcat 7 -> ColdFusion 10. We use the IIS rewrite module (web.config). OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

When requesting a URL like `/stylesheets/merge.css`, `/scripts/merge.js` or `/api/service.json` that is rewritten to a `.cfm` file (ColdFusion), which returns dynamic content in the corresponding MIME type, the request takes *exactly* 60 seconds to receive the response. This delay does not occur when the rewrite points to a static file that is handled by IIS. It also doesn't happen with non-rewrites.

Now here comes the strange part: **This issue only happens on Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge and only on 1 out of the 50 websites.**

- The TTFB is within the expected range (below 100 ms), the content download (10-100 KB) is delayed by *exactly* 60 seconds.
- We tested with IE 11 and Edge on 3 different machines/networks. Same results on all of them.
- I recreated the affected site in IIS, no change.

Example of a rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="stylesheet" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^stylesheets/merged/([^/]+)\.css$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/symlink/design/stylesheets/merge.cfm?mode={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

What could possibly be the reason for this? How can I investigate this further?

Comment: With such stable reproducible steps, you can use tools such as Fiddler/Wireshark on client side, and Failed Request Tracing on server side to dive deeper.

Comment: It seems fine with Fiddler (as all other browsers do) and there's no failed request, just a huge delay. It has to be related to IIS, but I don't know where to check.

Comment: FRT can be used for successful requests too. Use that to check the time spent inside IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out. It was a misconfiguration on our host's side. The used load balancer (HAProxy) closed all HTTP connections disallowing chunked transfer encoding. IE/Edge being the only browsers that do not fallback apparently.